# enlarges button with enlarging div

Tags: css

I would like to have a button in a div with a certain height and background color that enlarges when you hover over. But I don’t want the hight of the div to change. see pic below. is there any way to do this with just css?[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
transform: scale(factor);
```

Add

```
transition: property transition-timing transition-type;
```

if you want a smooth transition over time.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.outer:hover .circle {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="circle"></div><code>&lt;div&gt;</code>
</div>
```